# SegNet - architecture & image size

Tags: artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, caffe

Im trying to train my own dataset on SegNet (with caffe), I prepared the dataset same as [segnet tutorial](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/segnet/tutorial.html). when I try to run the train, it shows me this error:

```
I0915 05:08:08.281393 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer data
I0915 05:08:08.281424 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer data
I0915 05:08:08.281436 45783 net.cpp:368] data -> data
I0915 05:08:08.281469 45783 net.cpp:368] data -> label
I0915 05:08:08.281497 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up data
I0915 05:08:08.281512 45783 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:41] Opening file /home/ubuntu/full_conv_net/data.txt
I0915 05:08:08.291044 45783 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:51] Shuffling data
I0915 05:08:08.292588 45783 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:56] A total of 9999 examples.
I0915 05:08:08.297546 45783 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:109] output data size: 6,3,480,360
I0915 05:08:08.302744 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 3 480 360 (3110400)
I0915 05:08:08.302783 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 1 480 360 (1036800)
I0915 05:08:08.302795 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer label_data_1_split
I0915 05:08:08.302814 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer label_data_1_split
I0915 05:08:08.302822 45783 net.cpp:410] label_data_1_split <- label
I0915 05:08:08.302842 45783 net.cpp:368] label_data_1_split -> label_data_1_split_0
I0915 05:08:08.302865 45783 net.cpp:368] label_data_1_split -> label_data_1_split_1
I0915 05:08:08.302875 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up label_data_1_split
I0915 05:08:08.302891 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 1 480 360 (1036800)
I0915 05:08:08.302906 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 1 480 360 (1036800)
I0915 05:08:08.302911 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv1_1
I0915 05:08:08.302932 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv1_1
I0915 05:08:08.302940 45783 net.cpp:410] conv1_1 <- data
I0915 05:08:08.302949 45783 net.cpp:368] conv1_1 -> conv1_1
I0915 05:08:08.302963 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv1_1
I0915 05:08:08.303208 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 64 480 360 (66355200)
I0915 05:08:08.303234 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv1_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.303252 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv1_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.303266 45783 net.cpp:410] conv1_1_bn <- conv1_1
I0915 05:08:08.303275 45783 net.cpp:357] conv1_1_bn -> conv1_1 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.303318 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv1_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.304715 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 64 480 360 (66355200)
I0915 05:08:08.304738 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu1_1
I0915 05:08:08.304751 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu1_1
I0915 05:08:08.304756 45783 net.cpp:410] relu1_1 <- conv1_1
I0915 05:08:08.304767 45783 net.cpp:357] relu1_1 -> conv1_1 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.304776 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu1_1
I0915 05:08:08.304795 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 64 480 360 (66355200)
I0915 05:08:08.304806 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv1_2
I0915 05:08:08.304816 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv1_2
I0915 05:08:08.304822 45783 net.cpp:410] conv1_2 <- conv1_1
I0915 05:08:08.304862 45783 net.cpp:368] conv1_2 -> conv1_2
I0915 05:08:08.304878 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv1_2
I0915 05:08:08.306807 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 64 480 360 (66355200)
I0915 05:08:08.306831 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv1_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.306845 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv1_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.306850 45783 net.cpp:410] conv1_2_bn <- conv1_2
I0915 05:08:08.306859 45783 net.cpp:357] conv1_2_bn -> conv1_2 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.306870 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv1_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.310724 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 64 480 360 (66355200)
I0915 05:08:08.310745 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu1_2
I0915 05:08:08.310755 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu1_2
I0915 05:08:08.310760 45783 net.cpp:410] relu1_2 <- conv1_2
I0915 05:08:08.310767 45783 net.cpp:357] relu1_2 -> conv1_2 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.310775 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu1_2
I0915 05:08:08.310781 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 64 480 360 (66355200)
I0915 05:08:08.310786 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer pool1
I0915 05:08:08.310801 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer pool1
I0915 05:08:08.310808 45783 net.cpp:410] pool1 <- conv1_2
I0915 05:08:08.310818 45783 net.cpp:368] pool1 -> pool1
I0915 05:08:08.310830 45783 net.cpp:368] pool1 -> pool1_mask
I0915 05:08:08.310840 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up pool1
I0915 05:08:08.310863 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 64 240 180 (16588800)
I0915 05:08:08.310876 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 64 240 180 (16588800)
I0915 05:08:08.310883 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv2_1
I0915 05:08:08.310894 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv2_1
I0915 05:08:08.310900 45783 net.cpp:410] conv2_1 <- pool1
I0915 05:08:08.310909 45783 net.cpp:368] conv2_1 -> conv2_1
I0915 05:08:08.310919 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv2_1
I0915 05:08:08.313663 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 128 240 180 (33177600)
I0915 05:08:08.313685 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv2_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.313695 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv2_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.313701 45783 net.cpp:410] conv2_1_bn <- conv2_1
I0915 05:08:08.313714 45783 net.cpp:357] conv2_1_bn -> conv2_1 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.313724 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv2_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.315155 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 128 240 180 (33177600)
I0915 05:08:08.315177 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu2_1
I0915 05:08:08.315186 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu2_1
I0915 05:08:08.315192 45783 net.cpp:410] relu2_1 <- conv2_1
I0915 05:08:08.315199 45783 net.cpp:357] relu2_1 -> conv2_1 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.315208 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu2_1
I0915 05:08:08.315215 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 128 240 180 (33177600)
I0915 05:08:08.315220 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv2_2
I0915 05:08:08.315230 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv2_2
I0915 05:08:08.315235 45783 net.cpp:410] conv2_2 <- conv2_1
I0915 05:08:08.315246 45783 net.cpp:368] conv2_2 -> conv2_2
I0915 05:08:08.315254 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv2_2
I0915 05:08:08.320454 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 128 240 180 (33177600)
I0915 05:08:08.320478 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv2_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.320493 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv2_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.320499 45783 net.cpp:410] conv2_2_bn <- conv2_2
I0915 05:08:08.320526 45783 net.cpp:357] conv2_2_bn -> conv2_2 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.320536 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv2_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.320737 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 128 240 180 (33177600)
I0915 05:08:08.320758 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu2_2
I0915 05:08:08.320767 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu2_2
I0915 05:08:08.320772 45783 net.cpp:410] relu2_2 <- conv2_2
I0915 05:08:08.320780 45783 net.cpp:357] relu2_2 -> conv2_2 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.320786 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu2_2
I0915 05:08:08.320793 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 128 240 180 (33177600)
I0915 05:08:08.320798 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer pool2
I0915 05:08:08.320806 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer pool2
I0915 05:08:08.320811 45783 net.cpp:410] pool2 <- conv2_2
I0915 05:08:08.320821 45783 net.cpp:368] pool2 -> pool2
I0915 05:08:08.320829 45783 net.cpp:368] pool2 -> pool2_mask
I0915 05:08:08.320837 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up pool2
I0915 05:08:08.320845 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 128 120 90 (8294400)
I0915 05:08:08.320852 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 128 120 90 (8294400)
I0915 05:08:08.320857 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3_1
I0915 05:08:08.320869 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv3_1
I0915 05:08:08.320874 45783 net.cpp:410] conv3_1 <- pool2
I0915 05:08:08.320883 45783 net.cpp:368] conv3_1 -> conv3_1
I0915 05:08:08.320890 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv3_1
I0915 05:08:08.330775 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 256 120 90 (16588800)
I0915 05:08:08.330801 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.330813 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv3_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.330819 45783 net.cpp:410] conv3_1_bn <- conv3_1
I0915 05:08:08.330827 45783 net.cpp:357] conv3_1_bn -> conv3_1 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.330837 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv3_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.330896 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 256 120 90 (16588800)
I0915 05:08:08.330914 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu3_1
I0915 05:08:08.330922 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu3_1
I0915 05:08:08.330927 45783 net.cpp:410] relu3_1 <- conv3_1
I0915 05:08:08.330937 45783 net.cpp:357] relu3_1 -> conv3_1 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.330945 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu3_1
I0915 05:08:08.330951 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 256 120 90 (16588800)
I0915 05:08:08.330956 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3_2
I0915 05:08:08.330965 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv3_2
I0915 05:08:08.330968 45783 net.cpp:410] conv3_2 <- conv3_1
I0915 05:08:08.330978 45783 net.cpp:368] conv3_2 -> conv3_2
I0915 05:08:08.330986 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv3_2
I0915 05:08:08.350402 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 256 120 90 (16588800)
I0915 05:08:08.350425 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.350436 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv3_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.350442 45783 net.cpp:410] conv3_2_bn <- conv3_2
I0915 05:08:08.350450 45783 net.cpp:357] conv3_2_bn -> conv3_2 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.350460 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv3_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.350520 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 256 120 90 (16588800)
I0915 05:08:08.350540 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu3_2
I0915 05:08:08.350548 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu3_2
I0915 05:08:08.350554 45783 net.cpp:410] relu3_2 <- conv3_2
I0915 05:08:08.350560 45783 net.cpp:357] relu3_2 -> conv3_2 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.350569 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu3_2
I0915 05:08:08.350574 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 256 120 90 (16588800)
I0915 05:08:08.350579 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3_3
I0915 05:08:08.350587 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv3_3
I0915 05:08:08.350592 45783 net.cpp:410] conv3_3 <- conv3_2
I0915 05:08:08.350601 45783 net.cpp:368] conv3_3 -> conv3_3
I0915 05:08:08.350610 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv3_3
I0915 05:08:08.370225 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 256 120 90 (16588800)
I0915 05:08:08.370256 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv3_3_bn
I0915 05:08:08.370270 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv3_3_bn
I0915 05:08:08.370296 45783 net.cpp:410] conv3_3_bn <- conv3_3
I0915 05:08:08.370306 45783 net.cpp:357] conv3_3_bn -> conv3_3 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.370314 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv3_3_bn
I0915 05:08:08.370376 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 256 120 90 (16588800)
I0915 05:08:08.370393 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu3_3
I0915 05:08:08.370404 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu3_3
I0915 05:08:08.370410 45783 net.cpp:410] relu3_3 <- conv3_3
I0915 05:08:08.370417 45783 net.cpp:357] relu3_3 -> conv3_3 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.370424 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu3_3
I0915 05:08:08.370430 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 256 120 90 (16588800)
I0915 05:08:08.370435 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer pool3
I0915 05:08:08.370445 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer pool3
I0915 05:08:08.370450 45783 net.cpp:410] pool3 <- conv3_3
I0915 05:08:08.370456 45783 net.cpp:368] pool3 -> pool3
I0915 05:08:08.370465 45783 net.cpp:368] pool3 -> pool3_mask
I0915 05:08:08.370473 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up pool3
I0915 05:08:08.370482 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 256 60 45 (4147200)
I0915 05:08:08.370488 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 256 60 45 (4147200)
I0915 05:08:08.370493 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv4_1
I0915 05:08:08.370504 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv4_1
I0915 05:08:08.370509 45783 net.cpp:410] conv4_1 <- pool3
I0915 05:08:08.370519 45783 net.cpp:368] conv4_1 -> conv4_1
I0915 05:08:08.370528 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv4_1
I0915 05:08:08.409204 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 60 45 (8294400)
I0915 05:08:08.409225 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv4_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.409238 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv4_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.409245 45783 net.cpp:410] conv4_1_bn <- conv4_1
I0915 05:08:08.409255 45783 net.cpp:357] conv4_1_bn -> conv4_1 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.409263 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv4_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.409288 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 60 45 (8294400)
I0915 05:08:08.409304 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu4_1
I0915 05:08:08.409312 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu4_1
I0915 05:08:08.409317 45783 net.cpp:410] relu4_1 <- conv4_1
I0915 05:08:08.409324 45783 net.cpp:357] relu4_1 -> conv4_1 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.409332 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu4_1
I0915 05:08:08.409337 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 60 45 (8294400)
I0915 05:08:08.409343 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv4_2
I0915 05:08:08.409350 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv4_2
I0915 05:08:08.409355 45783 net.cpp:410] conv4_2 <- conv4_1
I0915 05:08:08.409365 45783 net.cpp:368] conv4_2 -> conv4_2
I0915 05:08:08.409373 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv4_2
I0915 05:08:08.486438 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 60 45 (8294400)
I0915 05:08:08.486469 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv4_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.486484 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv4_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.486490 45783 net.cpp:410] conv4_2_bn <- conv4_2
I0915 05:08:08.486500 45783 net.cpp:357] conv4_2_bn -> conv4_2 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.486508 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv4_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.486536 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 60 45 (8294400)
I0915 05:08:08.486554 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu4_2
I0915 05:08:08.486563 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu4_2
I0915 05:08:08.486568 45783 net.cpp:410] relu4_2 <- conv4_2
I0915 05:08:08.486575 45783 net.cpp:357] relu4_2 -> conv4_2 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.486582 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu4_2
I0915 05:08:08.486588 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 60 45 (8294400)
I0915 05:08:08.486593 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv4_3
I0915 05:08:08.486606 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv4_3
I0915 05:08:08.486611 45783 net.cpp:410] conv4_3 <- conv4_2
I0915 05:08:08.486629 45783 net.cpp:368] conv4_3 -> conv4_3
I0915 05:08:08.486639 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv4_3
I0915 05:08:08.563442 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 60 45 (8294400)
I0915 05:08:08.563464 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv4_3_bn
I0915 05:08:08.563501 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv4_3_bn
I0915 05:08:08.563514 45783 net.cpp:410] conv4_3_bn <- conv4_3
I0915 05:08:08.563526 45783 net.cpp:357] conv4_3_bn -> conv4_3 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.563536 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv4_3_bn
I0915 05:08:08.563577 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 60 45 (8294400)
I0915 05:08:08.563592 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu4_3
I0915 05:08:08.563602 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu4_3
I0915 05:08:08.563607 45783 net.cpp:410] relu4_3 <- conv4_3
I0915 05:08:08.563614 45783 net.cpp:357] relu4_3 -> conv4_3 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.563621 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu4_3
I0915 05:08:08.563628 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 60 45 (8294400)
I0915 05:08:08.563633 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer pool4
I0915 05:08:08.563642 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer pool4
I0915 05:08:08.563647 45783 net.cpp:410] pool4 <- conv4_3
I0915 05:08:08.563653 45783 net.cpp:368] pool4 -> pool4
I0915 05:08:08.563663 45783 net.cpp:368] pool4 -> pool4_mask
I0915 05:08:08.563670 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up pool4
I0915 05:08:08.563679 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 30 23 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.563685 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 30 23 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.563690 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_1
I0915 05:08:08.563699 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_1
I0915 05:08:08.563704 45783 net.cpp:410] conv5_1 <- pool4
I0915 05:08:08.563714 45783 net.cpp:368] conv5_1 -> conv5_1
I0915 05:08:08.563721 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_1
I0915 05:08:08.640889 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 30 23 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.640913 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.640926 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.640933 45783 net.cpp:410] conv5_1_bn <- conv5_1
I0915 05:08:08.640941 45783 net.cpp:357] conv5_1_bn -> conv5_1 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.640950 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_1_bn
I0915 05:08:08.640974 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 30 23 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.640987 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu5_1
I0915 05:08:08.640995 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu5_1
I0915 05:08:08.641000 45783 net.cpp:410] relu5_1 <- conv5_1
I0915 05:08:08.641007 45783 net.cpp:357] relu5_1 -> conv5_1 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.641013 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu5_1
I0915 05:08:08.641019 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 30 23 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.641024 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_2
I0915 05:08:08.641032 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_2
I0915 05:08:08.641037 45783 net.cpp:410] conv5_2 <- conv5_1
I0915 05:08:08.641044 45783 net.cpp:368] conv5_2 -> conv5_2
I0915 05:08:08.641052 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_2
I0915 05:08:08.718438 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 30 23 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.718461 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.718472 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.718479 45783 net.cpp:410] conv5_2_bn <- conv5_2
I0915 05:08:08.718492 45783 net.cpp:357] conv5_2_bn -> conv5_2 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.718500 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_2_bn
I0915 05:08:08.718528 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 30 23 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.718542 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu5_2
I0915 05:08:08.718551 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu5_2
I0915 05:08:08.718556 45783 net.cpp:410] relu5_2 <- conv5_2
I0915 05:08:08.718565 45783 net.cpp:357] relu5_2 -> conv5_2 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.718572 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu5_2
I0915 05:08:08.718580 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 30 23 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.718585 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_3
I0915 05:08:08.718592 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_3
I0915 05:08:08.718597 45783 net.cpp:410] conv5_3 <- conv5_2
I0915 05:08:08.718605 45783 net.cpp:368] conv5_3 -> conv5_3
I0915 05:08:08.718613 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_3
I0915 05:08:08.795704 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 30 23 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.795727 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_3_bn
I0915 05:08:08.795769 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_3_bn
I0915 05:08:08.795783 45783 net.cpp:410] conv5_3_bn <- conv5_3
I0915 05:08:08.795791 45783 net.cpp:357] conv5_3_bn -> conv5_3 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.795800 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_3_bn
I0915 05:08:08.795822 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 30 23 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.795837 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu5_3
I0915 05:08:08.795845 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu5_3
I0915 05:08:08.795850 45783 net.cpp:410] relu5_3 <- conv5_3
I0915 05:08:08.795857 45783 net.cpp:357] relu5_3 -> conv5_3 (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.795864 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu5_3
I0915 05:08:08.795871 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 30 23 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.795876 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer pool5
I0915 05:08:08.795891 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer pool5
I0915 05:08:08.795895 45783 net.cpp:410] pool5 <- conv5_3
I0915 05:08:08.795902 45783 net.cpp:368] pool5 -> pool5
I0915 05:08:08.795912 45783 net.cpp:368] pool5 -> pool5_mask
I0915 05:08:08.795920 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up pool5
I0915 05:08:08.795929 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 15 12 (552960)
I0915 05:08:08.795935 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 15 12 (552960)
I0915 05:08:08.795940 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer upsample5
I0915 05:08:08.795954 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer upsample5
I0915 05:08:08.795965 45783 net.cpp:410] upsample5 <- pool5
I0915 05:08:08.795971 45783 net.cpp:410] upsample5 <- pool5_mask
I0915 05:08:08.795979 45783 net.cpp:368] upsample5 -> pool5_D
I0915 05:08:08.795991 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up upsample5
I0915 05:08:08.796003 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 23 30 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.796010 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_3_D
I0915 05:08:08.796018 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_3_D
I0915 05:08:08.796023 45783 net.cpp:410] conv5_3_D <- pool5_D
I0915 05:08:08.796036 45783 net.cpp:368] conv5_3_D -> conv5_3_D
I0915 05:08:08.796044 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_3_D
I0915 05:08:08.873011 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 23 30 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.873037 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_3_D_bn
I0915 05:08:08.873050 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_3_D_bn
I0915 05:08:08.873057 45783 net.cpp:410] conv5_3_D_bn <- conv5_3_D
I0915 05:08:08.873066 45783 net.cpp:357] conv5_3_D_bn -> conv5_3_D (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.873075 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_3_D_bn
I0915 05:08:08.873106 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 23 30 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.873122 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu5_3_D
I0915 05:08:08.873131 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu5_3_D
I0915 05:08:08.873136 45783 net.cpp:410] relu5_3_D <- conv5_3_D
I0915 05:08:08.873142 45783 net.cpp:357] relu5_3_D -> conv5_3_D (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.873149 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu5_3_D
I0915 05:08:08.873155 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 23 30 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.873160 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_2_D
I0915 05:08:08.873169 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_2_D
I0915 05:08:08.873174 45783 net.cpp:410] conv5_2_D <- conv5_3_D
I0915 05:08:08.873184 45783 net.cpp:368] conv5_2_D -> conv5_2_D
I0915 05:08:08.873193 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_2_D
I0915 05:08:08.950387 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 23 30 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.950407 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_2_D_bn
I0915 05:08:08.950418 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_2_D_bn
I0915 05:08:08.950424 45783 net.cpp:410] conv5_2_D_bn <- conv5_2_D
I0915 05:08:08.950435 45783 net.cpp:357] conv5_2_D_bn -> conv5_2_D (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.950444 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_2_D_bn
I0915 05:08:08.950475 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 23 30 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.950490 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu5_2_D
I0915 05:08:08.950498 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu5_2_D
I0915 05:08:08.950503 45783 net.cpp:410] relu5_2_D <- conv5_2_D
I0915 05:08:08.950515 45783 net.cpp:357] relu5_2_D -> conv5_2_D (in-place)
I0915 05:08:08.950552 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu5_2_D
I0915 05:08:08.950561 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 23 30 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:08.950570 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_1_D
I0915 05:08:08.950579 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_1_D
I0915 05:08:08.950587 45783 net.cpp:410] conv5_1_D <- conv5_2_D
I0915 05:08:08.950594 45783 net.cpp:368] conv5_1_D -> conv5_1_D
I0915 05:08:08.950603 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_1_D
I0915 05:08:09.027575 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 23 30 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:09.027601 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer conv5_1_D_bn
I0915 05:08:09.027611 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer conv5_1_D_bn
I0915 05:08:09.027618 45783 net.cpp:410] conv5_1_D_bn <- conv5_1_D
I0915 05:08:09.027627 45783 net.cpp:357] conv5_1_D_bn -> conv5_1_D (in-place)
I0915 05:08:09.027638 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up conv5_1_D_bn
I0915 05:08:09.027668 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 23 30 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:09.027683 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer relu5_1_D
I0915 05:08:09.027691 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer relu5_1_D
I0915 05:08:09.027696 45783 net.cpp:410] relu5_1_D <- conv5_1_D
I0915 05:08:09.027704 45783 net.cpp:357] relu5_1_D -> conv5_1_D (in-place)
I0915 05:08:09.027710 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up relu5_1_D
I0915 05:08:09.027716 45783 net.cpp:127] Top shape: 6 512 23 30 (2119680)
I0915 05:08:09.027727 45783 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer upsample4
I0915 05:08:09.027739 45783 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer upsample4
I0915 05:08:09.027745 45783 net.cpp:410] upsample4 <- conv5_1_D
I0915 05:08:09.027751 45783 net.cpp:410] upsample4 <- pool4_mask
I0915 05:08:09.027758 45783 net.cpp:368] upsample4 -> pool4_D
I0915 05:08:09.027767 45783 net.cpp:120] Setting up upsample4
F0915 05:08:09.027793 45783 upsample_layer.cpp:63] Check failed: bottom[0]->height() == bottom[1]->height() (23 vs. 30) 
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fb4ab65ddaa  (unknown)
    @     0x7fb4ab65dce4  (unknown)
    @     0x7fb4ab65d6e6  (unknown)
    @     0x7fb4ab660687  (unknown)
    @     0x7fb4aba6e718  caffe::UpsampleLayer<>::Reshape()
    @     0x7fb4ab9d4bf2  caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x7fb4ab9d6952  caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x7fb4ab9bcbf0  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x7fb4ab9bdbc3  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7fb4ab9bdd96  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @           0x40c5d0  caffe::GetSolver<>()
    @           0x406611  train()
    @           0x404bb1  main
    @     0x7fb4aab6ff45  (unknown)
    @           0x40515d  (unknown)
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
```

I tried to resize the images in a few versions (360X480, h/3 w/3, 256X256) and still it shows me (in a different layers) this error (in a different numbers). the problem is in my pool layers? kernel size? tnanks for helping.

Comment: Can you post the .prototxt and the stdout from caffe.

Comment: sure. the [.prototxt](https://github.com/alexgkendall/SegNet-Tutorial/blob/master/Models/segnet_train.prototxt) - but only with 2 labels (last `num_output: 2`. and i posted the stout of caffe in the post.

Comment: Can you post the entire stdout. Not just the error part.

Comment: @malreddysid I just edit the post and put the entire stdout.

Comment: I solve it. the Dconv was rotated wrong (h and w), i just change the `upsample_h` and `upsample_w`. but now I have another problem:
`I0915 08:11:52.191599 48647 solver.cpp:251] Learning Rate Policy: step
F0915 08:11:52.661870 48647 math_functions.cu:123] Check failed: status == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS (11 vs. 0)  CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR
*** Check failure stack trace: ***`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. the issue was that my data had different input dimensions to the example. I had modified the `upsample_param` to match my dataset's pooling dimensions.